# Django extra-views for one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, one-to-many, relationships

I'm trying to use extra-views for django to create one-to-many relationship.
I have a model of item in my shop:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(
        'Название товара'
    )

    company = models.TextField(
        'Производитель'
    )
    category = models.TextField(
        'Категория'
    )
    photo = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to='photos/%Y/%m'
    )
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        'Цена'
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        'Количество'
    )
    text = models.TextField('Описание товара', blank=True, null=True)
```

A model for Images:

```
class Images(models.Model):
    Image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, 
    upload_to='photos/other/%Y/%m')
```

And relationship model:

```
class ItemImages(models.Model):
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item, default=1, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img_id = models.ForeignKey(Images, default=1, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And basically I'm trying to use it like this:

```
 class ImgInLine(InlineFormSet):
    model = Images


class ChainInLine(InlineFormSet):
    model = ItemImages


class AddItemView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateWithInlinesView):
    permission_required = 'shop.add_item'
    raise_exception = True
    model = Item
    fields = ['name', 'company', 'category', 'text', 'photo', 'price', 
             'quantity']
    inlines = [ImgInLine, ChainInLine]
```

and I'm getting error:

> ValueError at /add/ 'shop.Images' has no ForeignKey to 'shop.Item'.

So I have no clue how this thing works.

Comment: The error message tells it. Your `Images` model does not have a `ForeignKey` to `Item`, so you can't use it as an inline to `Item`.

Comment: @Selcuk mb you can a recommend method of editing two models at once?

Comment: There are no nested inlines by default but you can implement your own. Have a look at https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline